# XSLT for Selenium Results for TeamCity

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, teamcity

I have gotten our TeamCity build server to execute the Selenium suite from the command line successfully, and I would like to have the results posted back to TeamCity.

Is there an XSLT for taking the results of Selenium and turning it into a format that TeamCity can read? I saw something in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6571851/3256) about using nxslt3.exe to do it, but I can't find the template anywhere

***NOTE***: I cannot use the c# export function of the Selenium IDE, I have to use the html templates to execute the tests.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem with our Play project Selenium tests. They return their result as a HTML file of the tests, which i can not easily import into TeamCity. To solve this i have written a parser which parses the HTML files and outputs the testresults to TeamCity via service messages.

For more information see this blog post: http://q42.nl/importing-play-selenium-tests-in-teamcity or https://github.com/crunchie84/play-seleniumresults-parser for directly downloading the tool/sourcecode

Comment: your blog link is broken... does that still live anywhere accessible?