# How can I install Selenium RC in TeamCity?

Tags: selenium, testing, teamcity

I need to link Selenium IDE to automate the tests I have in my Firefox suite, but I don't know how to install Selenium in TeamCity.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, you don't. You have to record your tests in firefox, and then import them as a unit tests into your project (Maven for Java, NUnit for C# etc.). Then, run those tests as any others. Here are some solutions, you might want to take a look

- [Running selenium automation tests on remote teamcity build agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648491/running-selenium-automation-tests-on-remote-teamcity-build-agent)
- [Automate Selenium tests on TeamCity Continuous Integration server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524159/automate-selenium-tests-on-teamcity-continuous-integration-server)
- [Best way to wire up Selenium test automation](https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000764304-Best-way-to-wire-up-Selenium-test-automation)
- [How to setup TeamCity for run selenium auto tests?](https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207225005-How-to-setup-TeamCity-for-run-selenium-auto-tests-)